# ERROR: Named volume "mongodb_config:/data/configdb:rw" is used in service "mongo" but no declaration was found in the volumes section

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I am having this error while running my docker- compose command "docker-compose up -d mongo". Please help me to find a solution . Thanks in advance .

My docker-compose.yml looks like this .

```
version: '3'
services:
    mongo:
        image: mongo:4.2.0
        ports:
            - "27017:27017"
        volumes:
            - mongodb:/data/db
            - mongodb_config:/data/configdb
 
    mongo-express:
        image: mongo-express
        restart: unless-stopped
        ports:
            - "8081:8081"
volumes:
    mongo:
        external: true
```

please help .

Answer (score 2):

The error message means you should create the volume first. Try this:

```
version: '3'
services:
    mongo:
        image: mongo:4.2.0
        ports:
            - "27017:27017"
        volumes:
            - mongodb:/data/db
            - mongodb_config:/data/configdb
 
    mongo-express:
        image: mongo-express
        restart: unless-stopped
        ports:
            - "8081:8081"

volumes:   # use volume by local driver, so you can use the volume directly
  mongodb:
    driver: local
  mongodb_config:
    driver: local
```

See also [Use volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/)